# Javascript syntactic sugar for object value setter

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way to do this in one line

```
( node.innerText || node.textContent ) = text
// node = DOM node  
// text = string
```

Obviously the above does not work.

Comment: I tested something like `node.innerText ? node.innerText = text : node.textContent = text` and seems to work fine, even though is not so sweet as syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `node.innerText = node.textContent = text`, which is harmless.

Comment: I like this. It will work for the scenario above, but I'll still keep looking for a few more minutes before I accept

Comment: @JibiAbraham Totally agree, it would be awesome if someone could come up with an actual conditional assignment. I'm pretty pessimistic though, because looking at the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), it doesn't leave much room for maneuvring.

Answer (score 2):

One could do it like this:

```
node['textContent' in node? 'textContent' : 'innerText'] = text
```

Comment: fancy. I might use this somewhere. but still quite verbose

Comment: Then how about `window.TEXTPROP = 'textContent' in node? 'textContent' : 'innerText'` and `node[TEXTPROP] = text`?

Comment: that seems like something I could use at a higher level. nice one

Answer (score 1):

First, not-so-compact attempt

```
node.innerText ? node.innerText = text : node.textContent = text
```

Comment: ahhh, but this is again too verbose

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery to shorten your syntax

use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method

so your code will be

```
if($(selector).text() = text){
// your code here
}
```